# PETG Benchy boogers and stringing

Tags: petg, direct-drive

The Benchy looks good for the most part except for some boogers on the chimney

[image: Photo of a printed benchy with zits on the chimney]

And some stringing on the bow, near the front deck.

[image: Photo of the top of a printed benchy with minor stringing problems]

Here are my settings. On another roll of Inland PETG, I printed a Benchy at 30 mm/s and it came out perfect. Is there any way to improve my results at higher speeds? Maybe 4 or 5 for retraction and/or faster retraction speeds? I figure I ask before taking shots in the dark. I was told to not go below 235 °C for PETG so that seems like lowering the temperature is out of the question.

Any ideas? Below are my settings.

The printer is a Sovol Sv01 Pro (this is similar to an Ender 3 S1)

- direct drive extruder
- Creality silent board
- CR Touch
- Marlin 2.0
- hot end like and Ender 3 Pro with an MK8
- PEI sheet
- K value 2.0 - this was the factory setting

All the parts are pretty new since I bought the printer on an Amazon Prime day about a month ago.

Settings (using Inland PETG - Yellow):

- a few days ago it had a 6hr session in a filament dryer
- 235 °C nozzle
- 70 °C bed
- retraction 3.0 mm
- print speed 40 mm/s
- print acceleration 500 mm/s
- jerk 12 mm/s

Comment: Is power loss recovery enabled? It will make blobs on each layer of your print (whether they're noticable varies by the geometry and slicing) by pausing to write status to the SD card on the first extrusion move of each layer. The extent of the blobbing will vary by how much the material oozes while dwelling and whether the material remelts when the nozzle sits in place on top of it.

Comment: What printer is this, is it a Sovol Sv01 Pro, or an Ender 3? Sovol is in the question, Ender in the tags.

Comment: @Oscar sorry that was a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

It is based on an ATMEGA chip, which may struggle with high CPU load.

The blobs can be likely avoided by reducing complexity of the model when slicing, see video

Comment: If this is the Sovol Sv01 Pro printer, it uses a 32-bit Creality 4.2.2 board, that is not an ATMega board.

Comment: It's a sovol but it's using the Creality Silent board.

Answer (score 1):

While you did use a dryer, the bumps on the surface look like moisture bubbles.  I've found it difficult to completely dry out PETG once it gains moisture, although drying is a great improvement.  Going straight from the filament dry pack to a dryer that feeds filament straight to the printer has done the best.